# Problem acessing php folder with Apache in XAMPP/WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, wamp

so, a few days ago I got an request of my older brother to remake and modernize a php website. So, I took the files and the SQL database files and implemented them easily in WAMP/XAMPP. So, hoping to get to work I've started Apache and PhpMyAdmin and tyed to open the folder with the php website. But, instead of opening, my browser is loding the folder for a few secs and afer shows me this:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the remote site did not respond properly after a certain period of time, or the connection established was incorrect because the connected host did not respond.

I was trying to use WAMP hoping to fix the error, buit didn't help. I alsaw reloaded the database on PhpMyAdmin, but it didn't help eather.

Comment: Presumably the database connection details in the php code don't point to the actual location of the mysql/mariadb server. Either that, or mysql is not running. This doesn't have anything to do with apache, or folders. We can't see the connection derails you used and don't know how your environment is configured so it's difficult to make a more specific suggestion.

Comment: `in WAMP/XAMPP`...you're using both at once??? Or you tried one then the other? Did you uninstall one and then install the other? It wasn't very clear.

Comment: @ADyson yeah, i only do use xampp rn. so, I've figured out about a part of the problem. So, the DB name, password aso didn't match, so i ajusted them to localhost, root, no password. but the problem didn't disappear.

Comment: Did you check that the database service is running and what port it runs on?

Comment: How was the domain of the site when your brother was working on it? And what is the domain now? Perhaps your installation needs a procedure which we call "migration", which involves the substitution of the domain name in URLs, in the PHP files and/or in the database.